# Why were the names changed in the final draft of The Lost Boys which refered to characters from Peter Pan's story?

Tags: production, the-lost-boys

From the [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093437/trivia?item=tr0710577) page for *The Lost Boys*:

> In the first draft of the script, the character of David was originally named Peter, and other characters also had names from the Peter Pan story. In the final draft, many name changes were made, but originally the two brothers were Michael and John (which was later changed to Sam) and the mother's name was Wendy.

But what was the reason for the character name changes in the final draft? Was it ever stated by officials?

Comment: God, I just hope the TV series doesn't suck. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR: The names were most likely updated to remove any whimsical tone of the characters.**

---

As others have commented, the names may have been changed to avoid copyright issues with Peter Pan. However, it's important to note that the overall tone of the film changed drastically between re-writes of the script, and the names were probably updated to reflect this.

The original script was intended as a G-rated film in the vein of "[Goonies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goonies)" or "[The Monster Squad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monster_Squad)" - a family-friendly movie inspired by the idea of Peter Pan as a vampire. When Joel Schumacher replaced Richard Donner as director, he reportedly hated that idea and wanted the movie to be more of a sexy, coming-of-age horror film. He brought on writer Jeffrey Boam to heavily modify the script, and it's likely at this point that the names were changed.

Within that context, the changes make sense. The entire film was given a darker, more biblical context (David's body enshrined in light at the end, for example). Rather than a "cutesy" gang of immortal children, Schumacher envisioned the vampires as more akin to the gangs of 1979's "[The Warriors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Warriors_(film))". The soundtrack originally called for Madonna songs (whereas Goonies used Cyndi Lauper), and that was obviously updated to more of a heavy metal "hairband" sound. And so forth.

Richard Donner left the project to make seminal action flick "[Lethal Weapon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lethal_Weapon)", and the resulting version of "[**The Lost Boys**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_Boys)" has become a classic vampire movie. As moviegoers, I'd say we were definitely the winners in this particular instance.

***Note:*** In addition to the facts on that IMDb [trivia page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0093437/trivia) you linked to, there are also some additional trivia tidbits on the page below, posted in celebration of the film's 25th anniversary.

http://www.indiewire.com/2012/08/5-things-you-might-not-know-about-the-lost-boys-on-its-25th-anniversary-251374/

Comment: The Goonies had Cyndi Lauper.

Comment: @TheWolfEmperor - true, but the original idea for The Lost Boys wanted Madonna, used in a similar manner to Cyndi Lauper in Goonies. I'll update the wording to make the meaning more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that "The Lost Boys" is what Peter Pan calls all of the boys in Neverland, and the fact that vampires don't age, I think literally naming all of the characters after characters in Peter Pan would have ended in a lawsuit.  Do I have factual knowledge of that?  No.  But I know a little about Intellectual Property and can guarantee that would have ended in litigation.

Comment: That was my guess as well. Plus, it would be a little too on-the-nose.

Comment: And Disney?  They don't mess around.

Comment: @AndrewMattson Disney's got nothing to say about this: https://www.plagiarismtoday.com/2015/10/21/peter-pan-and-the-copyright-that-never-grew-up/

Comment: It was a comment made in jest. Good bit of info, though. +1.

Comment: I don know if this is relavent but J.M. Barrie gave the copyright to Peter Pan to the Great Ormond Street Hosptial

Comment: To add a bit more, copyright was extended for perpetuity in the UK in a special act of Parliment meaning that the hospital receives royalties on all Peter Pan related material in the UK. It also covers other countries where the copyright is still in force for however long under their laws. http://www.gosh.org/about-us/peter-pan/copyright . Had Lost Boys kept the Peter Pan based references they may had to pay royalties or been sued as Johnny Bones suggests.